# Vite generating broken path for external static asset

Tags: vue.js, vite, astrojs

I have an Astro application using Vue components.

Inside the component, I reference an image:

```html
<img src="./assets/bme-logo.png" />
```

When I run vite build && vite start, the resulting html is:

```html
<img src="/node_modules/.pnpm/@visable-dev+vue@17.3.4_@visable-dev+routing@9.0.1_vue@3.2.47/node_modules/@visable-dev/vue/components/VisPageFooter/assets/bme-logo.png" data-v-7a2c58b2="">
```

I tried several things, for example importing the url with ES6 import:

```js
import bmeLogo from './assets/bme-logo.png';
```

But then Jest fails with:

```
Cannot find module './assets/bme-logo.png?url' from 'index.vue'
```

Comment: The `import` is the way to go according to the [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html). Sounds like the issue is with your Jest config and its loaders

Comment: Why you don't use the @, because with ./, you refer the current folder, and when it's build every files change.
```<img src="@/assets/bme-logo.png" />```

Comment: it was the jest config/ loaders.. thank you